# Is it possible to only display the largest calculated table column?

Tags: mysql

Below is a code to sum all rows in each column where the value of each column c(x) equals 1. It gives me six columns containing each calculated sum. Is it possible to only display the largest calculated column (c4 as given by the image below) in a neat way?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       (SELECT SUM(`vote_candidate_1`) 
          FROM `votes` 
         WHERE `vote_candidate_1` = 1) c1
     , (SELECT SUM(`vote_candidate_2`) 
          FROM `votes` 
         WHERE `vote_candidate_2` = 1) c2
     , (SELECT SUM(`vote_candidate_3`) 
          FROM `votes` 
         WHERE `vote_candidate_3` = 1) c3
     , (SELECT SUM(`vote_candidate_4`) 
          FROM `votes` 
         WHERE `vote_candidate_4` = 1) c4
     , (SELECT SUM(`vote_candidate_5`) 
          FROM `votes` 
         WHERE `vote_candidate_5` = 1) c5
     , (SELECT SUM(`vote_candidate_6`) 
          FROM `votes` 
         WHERE `vote_candidate_6` = 1) c6 
  FROM `votes`;
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atleast for 8.0 there's the GREATEST function. I would also suggest that you do one scan against the table instead of six:

```
SELECT GREATEST(SUM(CASE WHEN vote_candidate_1 = 1
                         THEN vote_candidate_1 END)
              , SUM(CASE WHEN vote_candidate_2 = 1 
                         THEN vote_candidate_2 END)
              , SUM(...)
               ) as ...
FROM votes;
```

Comment: Perfect! This did the trick. Just as a notice: I’m using 5.5 and GREATEST() work fantastic on that version too.  on a side note - is it possible to name the summed column?

Comment: Do you mean each sum, or result of GREATEST?

Comment: Yeah, exactly - on each sum.

Comment: You can do it in two steps: `SELECT GREATEST(c1, c2,...) FROM ( SELECT SUM(...) as c1, SUM(...) as c2,... FROM...) as T`

Comment: It kind of works but the column is now named “GREATEST(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6). I want it named c4.

Comment: Greatest(...) as c4

Comment: Ahh... what I mean is that I want the name of the greatest column... it just happens to be c4. If c2 was greatest I would like that name instead.

Comment: No, the name of the column must be static. You will have to add a column, say origin, that you can populate with that information